# Autohotkey: send umlaut if a/o/u pressed together with e?

Tags: autohotkey

I am looking for a solution to get an Umlaut when pressing/holding "e" and a corresponding letter, i.e. "e" together with "a" => ä, "e" together with "o" => ö, "e" together with "u" => ü

I can't find a solution in posts or forums. I tried the following for letter u but it doesn't work.

```
    *e::
        SendInput, {ü Down}
        Key = 
        Input, Key, V L1
    Return
    *e up::
        SendInput, {ü Up}
        Key = u
        Input,,T.01
        If u
            SendInput
    Return
```

Comment: Have you tried: `e & u::Send , ü`? Also, note that you will need `e::Send , e` to keep the native functionality of e and that it will fire on release instead of on press. Here is more info: https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#combo

Comment: Another option would be to use hotstrings, but pairing it with the letter e might be problematic as there are many normal words (in English) that have an eu or ea combination. Perhaps making it a different combination might make life easier. How about typing the same letter three times in a row? `:*?:uuu::ü` More info here: https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm

Comment: @EJE  e & u::Send , ü and  e::Send , e  is the perfect solution. Thank you!

Comment: Could you post as separate answer and the mark the answer as accepted to close this topic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

e & u::Send , ü and e::Send , e is a working solution.